# Eevee spot light volumetric lighting not starting or stopping at right location

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I'm trying to have a spot light in a dark room with volumetric lighting in Eevee. The trouble is the cone of light starts past where it should and stops before it should. Below is the first example. The cone of light should reach all the way to the circle where the spot light is hitting the wall, but it stops early despite the cone of principled volume continuing past the wall.

[image]

[image]

And here is the second example. When turned around and looking back at the spot light the volumetric light doesn't begin at the spot light, it starts far in front of the light. The cone of light should be coming out of the lit up circle I added but there is a gap. I've tried adjusting the clip start of the light and other settings but nothing seems to work, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it's not a limitation of Eevee's volumetrics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it necessary to operate at such a huge dimension? Almost 0.5 km ...
It always brings a lot of visual artefacts.

Here whole scene scaled down to 0.1 (for simplicity parented all to Empty and scaled).

[image]

[image]
Volumetric > Tile Size 4 px, Samples 16

Also your volume cube is in negative scale ... any reason for that?

BTW - Cone object is not needed, you can use Diffuse and Volumetric at the same material ...
Result is the same.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I hadn't realized the scale was so huge, and the volume cube negative scale was also a mistake. Very much appreciated :D

Comment: Edited with more details ...